# WAMP javascript mimetype configuration

Tags: javascript, wamp, mime-types, content-type

I have an error while opening php file with scripts:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html

I have already tried to configure mimetype file changing extensions open types to text/javascript, but it didn't gave me anything.

Furthermore, I have edited the httpd.conf adding

```
AddType text/javascript .js
```

and

```
 <Files "*.js">
     ForceType text/
 </Files>
```

but it also didn't give me any visible result.

*EDIT:
Apache somehow uses only default mimetype. What can prevent apache from using text/javascript?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by _opening php file with scripts_. Do you mean opening `.php` files that contain javascript code OR opening a php script from a piece of javascript? Also the mime-types are already defined and included into Apache using `TypesConfig conf/mime.types` and there is not reason to change/add to them unless you are doing something **VERY UNUSUAL**

Comment: @RiggsFolly for example, when i try to include jquery library with <script src='jquery.js'></script> - it gives me the error "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html". As a result - I can't use jquery library because it is not loaded properly.

Comment: Well try using the correct syntax for including a script `<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.js'></script>` then the problem will not be a problem.

Comment: Did that fix your problem?